# Two Cordova WebViews loading different html pages, how?

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview

I've got two tabs that both contain Cordova WebViews. How to I make them load up different html pages? Right now I can only get them to serve up identical pages...

I'm confused on how the config.xml file works, because currently both webviews are loading the same content:
`<content src="deviceTab/index.html"/>`, and I cannot put two of these content tags in the config file.

Do I have to make a separate config.xml for each webview? How do I tell the individual Cordova WebViews what config file to use?

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it with code

```
viewController.wwwFolderName = @"myfolder";
viewController.startPage = @"mypage.html"
```

More info [embeding webviews](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews)

Comment: so both webviews use the same config.xml file? Does that mean I remove the `<content>` tag from the file?

Comment: For those of you at home, I didn't remove the `<content>` tag and it still worked. @jcesar, thanks! It's always confusing for me wading through phonegap/cordova docs...